# Why Visual VM shows instances as zero for this String class?

Tags: java

This is my sample program which creates a String Object

```
public class TestingHeap {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        String str = new String("Hi This is sample String");

        try {
            //Thread.sleep(1111111);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

When i viewed the Heap Dump under VisualVM Tool the instances for that class is shown as zero

This is the screenshot wrt to above statement

[image]

If my assumption is wrong could you please let me know how to see the Objects present under Heap ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `main()` method is static and your code doesn't create an instance of `TestingHeap`. You could do so,

```
TestingHeap th = new TestingHeap(); // <-- add to main.
```

Comment: Excellent , i didn't thought of this , is it possible to find the String str ??

Comment: There are 11 500 instances .